# Preserving div ratio when height is the limiting factor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a "slide" div that is centered in the middle of the screen with a constant aspect ratio.

Combining this [trick](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) for centering and [this one](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) for the ratio, I came up with this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-content">
        Percentage sized and still centered.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* slide centered in the middle of the screen + width = 80% */
.slide {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}   

/* aspect ratio of 2:1 */
.slide:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%;
}

/* stretch the content to the slide size */
.slide > .slide-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3jph853w/

It works beautifully, expect on mobile in landscape view: the trick being based on width, the div is not resized properly and part of it "overflows" outside the screen. You can see it when you resize the fiddle output vertically.

How can I fix it ? I would rather keep it css only, with additional html markup is necessary. I am open to JS, but my project is Angular based and does not use jQuery.

Comment: `padding: 5% 7%` can do the trick because there is no reason to have fixed padding while the width and height are fluid. https://jsfiddle.net/3jph853w/

Comment: Thanks you're right, I will keep it in mind (I will probably also play with font size & line height). But the red div is still not resizing to keep the aspect ratio though (the width does not get smaller)

Comment: When I resize the fiddle output, the red rectangle definitely resizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a start

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3jph853w/2/) 100% of viewport
[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3jph853w/3/) 80% of viewport

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.slide{
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vh * 2);
  height: calc(100vw * 0.5);
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.slide-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <div class="slide-content">
    Percentage sized and still centered.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. I will combine the two with a media query to apply the 100% of viewport only on xs screens.

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align:center;` to the bottom of `.slide > .slide-content {`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to work. Size of the red div remains the same, so the text disappears outside the screen.